# Need to store images of tickets generated at random and save each image to a separate file using python

Tags: python, screenshot

I am generating 700 random tickets. I want to save image of each ticket and store it to a file. So that there are 700 such files, each containing image of an unique ticket. Here's the code i am using to generate tickets.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import sys
from tabulate import tabulate
import PIL
from PIL import Image


def getTickets():
    """
    #1 - Maintain array of total_numbers between 1 and 90. Initialize ticket_array as 3x9 array of 0s
    #2 - Generate 15 random indices from the array of total_indices.
    #3 - Compute index to drop the value into based on RULE #1, RULE #2
    #4 - Remove values used in the ticket from the base array (RULE #1, RULE #2)
    #5 - Repeat till 15 numbers are populated into ticket
    #6 - Sort numbers in every column of the ticket based on RULE #3
    """

    # Create a 2D array [3x9] of 0s
    ticket_array = np.zeros((3, 9), dtype=int)
    # Create an a list of numbers from 1 to 90.
    total_numbers = [num for num in range(1, 90)]
    # Create a list of tupele of all the indices of 3x9 ticket_array . i.e (0,0),(0,1),...,(2,8)
    total_indices = [(i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(9)]
    # Create an empty list to store 15 random indices to fill in the value.
    random_indices = []

    # Generate 15 random indices that satisfies RULE #1 and store them in random_indices array.

    first_row = random.sample(total_indices[:9], 5)
    second_row = random.sample(total_indices[9:18], 5)
    third_row = random.sample(total_indices[-9:], 5)

    for i in first_row:
        random_indices.append(i)

    for i in second_row:
        random_indices.append(i)

    for i in third_row:
        random_indices.append(i)

    # Populate values in the randomly generated indices such that it satisfies RULE #2 and replace the  value of the used value in total_numbers array by 0.

    for num in random_indices:
        if num[1] == 0:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[:10])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 1:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[10:20])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 2:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[20:30])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 3:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[30:40])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 4:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[40:50])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 5:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[50:60])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 6:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[60:70])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 7:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[70:80])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 8:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[80:89])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0

    # Sort the ticket_array column wise to satisfy the RULE #3

    for col in range(9):
        # if all the rows are filled with random number
        if(ticket_array[0][col] != 0 and ticket_array[1][col] != 0 and ticket_array[2][col] != 0):
            for row in range(2):
                if ticket_array[row][col] > ticket_array[row+1][col]:
                    temp = ticket_array[row][col]
                    ticket_array[row][col] = ticket_array[row+1][col]
                    ticket_array[row+1][col] = temp

        # if 1st and 2nd row are filled by random number
        elif(ticket_array[0][col] != 0 and ticket_array[1][col] != 0 and ticket_array[2][col] == 0):
            if ticket_array[0][col] > ticket_array[1][col]:
                temp = ticket_array[0][col]
                ticket_array[0][col] = ticket_array[1][col]
                ticket_array[1][col] = temp

        # if 1st and 3rd row are filled by random number
        elif(ticket_array[0][col] != 0 and ticket_array[2][col] != 0 and ticket_array[1][col] == 0):
            if ticket_array[0][col] > ticket_array[2][col]:
                temp = ticket_array[0][col]
                ticket_array[0][col] = ticket_array[2][col]
                ticket_array[2][col] = temp

        # if 2nd and 3rd rows are filled with random numbers
        elif(ticket_array[0][col] == 0 and ticket_array[1][col] != 0 and ticket_array[2][col] != 0):
            if ticket_array[1][col] > ticket_array[2][col]:
                temp = ticket_array[1][col]
                ticket_array[1][col] = ticket_array[2][col]
                ticket_array[2][col] = temp

    return ticket_array


if __name__ == "__main__":
    numberOfTickets = sys.argv[1]
    tickets = []
    for i in range(int(numberOfTickets)):
        ticket = getTickets()
        tickets.append(ticket)
    for ticket in tickets:
        image = tabulate(ticket, tablefmt="fancy_grid", numalign="center")
        text_file = open("Output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
        text_file.write(image)
        text_file.close()
        break
```

Now, I want all the tickets to be stored as output1, output2, output3 and so on.

Comment: _I do A ... and I want B._ Where is your code going from A to B? [mre]?  What problem do you face arriving at B? _I do not know how to do complex task X_ is not a valid question on SO - please do your research, add what you do and reduce your problem to a specific one. Read [ask] and do the  [tour] if you are unsure what is askable here.

Comment: Do you want to create the image? Or take a screenshot? There's a huge difference in those.

Comment: btw. your code makes no sense - why do a loop over all tickets if you `break` after the first one?  What is `image` ? NameError?

Comment: @PatrickArtner Please find the fresh code I have given in my answer. 700 randomly generated tickets stored in 700 .txt files. If you could help me convert all the .txt files to jpg at once.

Comment: Please refer to the code posted as an answer. Would want to convert all the .txt files to .jpg files at once. @JakubSzlaur

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import numpy as np
import sys
from tabulate import tabulate
import PIL
from PIL import Image


def getTickets():
    """
    #1 - Maintain array of total_numbers between 1 and 90. Initialize ticket_array as 3x9 array of 0s
    #2 - Generate 15 random indices from the array of total_indices.
    #3 - Compute index to drop the value into based on RULE #1, RULE #2
    #4 - Remove values used in the ticket from the base array (RULE #1, RULE #2)
    #5 - Repeat till 15 numbers are populated into ticket
    #6 - Sort numbers in every column of the ticket based on RULE #3
    """

    # Create a 2D array [3x9] of 0s
    ticket_array = np.zeros((3, 9), dtype=int)
    # Create an a list of numbers from 1 to 90.
    total_numbers = [num for num in range(1, 90)]
    # Create a list of tupele of all the indices of 3x9 ticket_array . i.e (0,0),(0,1),...,(2,8)
    total_indices = [(i, j) for i in range(3) for j in range(9)]
    # Create an empty list to store 15 random indices to fill in the value.
    random_indices = []

    # Generate 15 random indices that satisfies RULE #1 and store them in random_indices array.

    first_row = random.sample(total_indices[:9], 5)
    second_row = random.sample(total_indices[9:18], 5)
    third_row = random.sample(total_indices[-9:], 5)

    for i in first_row:
        random_indices.append(i)

    for i in second_row:
        random_indices.append(i)

    for i in third_row:
        random_indices.append(i)

    # Populate values in the randomly generated indices such that it satisfies RULE #2 and replace the  value of the used value in total_numbers array by 0.

    for num in random_indices:
        if num[1] == 0:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[:10])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 1:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[10:20])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 2:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[20:30])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 3:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[30:40])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 4:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[40:50])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 5:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[50:60])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 6:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[60:70])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 7:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[70:80])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0
        elif num[1] == 8:
            number = random.choice(total_numbers[80:89])
            ticket_array[num] = number
            total_numbers[total_numbers.index(number)] = 0

    # Sort the ticket_array column wise to satisfy the RULE #3

    for col in range(9):
        # if all the rows are filled with random number
        if(ticket_array[0][col] != 0 and ticket_array[1][col] != 0 and ticket_array[2][col] != 0):
            for row in range(2):
                if ticket_array[row][col] > ticket_array[row+1][col]:
                    temp = ticket_array[row][col]
                    ticket_array[row][col] = ticket_array[row+1][col]
                    ticket_array[row+1][col] = temp

        # if 1st and 2nd row are filled by random number
        elif(ticket_array[0][col] != 0 and ticket_array[1][col] != 0 and ticket_array[2][col] == 0):
            if ticket_array[0][col] > ticket_array[1][col]:
                temp = ticket_array[0][col]
                ticket_array[0][col] = ticket_array[1][col]
                ticket_array[1][col] = temp

        # if 1st and 3rd row are filled by random number
        elif(ticket_array[0][col] != 0 and ticket_array[2][col] != 0 and ticket_array[1][col] == 0):
            if ticket_array[0][col] > ticket_array[2][col]:
                temp = ticket_array[0][col]
                ticket_array[0][col] = ticket_array[2][col]
                ticket_array[2][col] = temp

        # if 2nd and 3rd rows are filled with random numbers
        elif(ticket_array[0][col] == 0 and ticket_array[1][col] != 0 and ticket_array[2][col] != 0):
            if ticket_array[1][col] > ticket_array[2][col]:
                temp = ticket_array[1][col]
                ticket_array[1][col] = ticket_array[2][col]
                ticket_array[2][col] = temp

    return ticket_array


if __name__ == "__main__":
    numberOfTickets = sys.argv[1]
    tickets = []
    for i in range(int(numberOfTickets)):
        ticket = getTickets()
        tickets.append(ticket)
    for ticket in tickets:
        image = tabulate(ticket, tablefmt="fancy_grid", numalign="center")
        import uuid
        filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"
        text_file = open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8")
        text_file.write(image)
        text_file.close()
```

Here's what I just generated. 700 tickets, each stored in a .txt file. If you could just help me convert all the .txt files to .jpg files at once.

Answer (score 0):

That pice of code you made is realy messy and dont know why did you make a simple task soo hard.

This example will give you some of the how to wite to a image.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
import time
import os

class Print_to_image:

    base_font = "courbi.ttf"
    base_size = 13
    base_color = (0, 0, 0)

    def save_image(self):
        if os.path.isdir(self.path):
            self.image.save(
                os.path.join(self.path, str(time.time()) + '.jpg')
            )
        else:
            self.image.save(self.path)

    def add_text(self, text, x_y_pos, size=base_size, color=base_color, font=base_font, **kwargs):
        pil_font = ImageFont.truetype(font=font, size=size, index=0)
        text_w_size, text_h_size = (0, 0)
        if isinstance(text, list) or isinstance(text, tuple):
            for text_seg in text:
                text_w_size, text_h_size = pil_font.getsize(str(text_seg))
                self.draw.text(x_y_pos, str(text_seg), color, font=pil_font, **kwargs)
                self.grid[0] += self.grid_inc[0] + text_w_size
            self.grid[0] = self.grid_inc[0]
        else:
            self.draw.text(x_y_pos, str(text), color, font=pil_font, **kwargs)
        self.grid[1] += self.grid_inc[1] + text_h_size

    def append_text(self, text, **kwargs):
        self.add_text(text, self.grid, **kwargs)

    def set_grid(self, base_x, base_y, inc_x, inc_y):
        self.grid_inc = [inc_x, inc_y]
        self.grid = [base_x, base_y]

    def __init__(self,  _path, _width, _heigth, color=(255, 255, 255)):
        self.path = _path
        self.image = Image.new('RGB', (_width, _heigth), color=color)
        self.draw = ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)
        self.grid_inc = [10, 10]
        self.grid = [10, 10]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ticket_a = Print_to_image('./', 250, 300)
    ticket_a.add_text('Some text', (20, 10))
    ticket_a.save_image()

    ticket_b = Print_to_image('./image_b.jpg', 500, 300)
    ticket_b.set_grid(10, 10, 10, 60)
    ticket_b.append_text(['Some numbers >', 2, 5, 7])
    ticket_b.append_text('More text', color='blue')
    ticket_b.save_image()
```